# Convert timestamp to string pandas python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have parse on zip file

```
import io
from zipfile import ZipFile
import pandas as pd
def read_zip(zip_fn, extract_fn=None):
    zf = ZipFile(zip_fn)
    if extract_fn:
       return zf.read(extract_fn)
    else:
       return {name:zf.read(name) for name in zf.namelist()}
df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(read_zip(r'C:\download\test.xlsx.zip', 'test.xlsx')))
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
print(tuples)
```

and I have data, this data print(tuples):

```
[(Timestamp('2020-01-13 00:00:00'), 'Ivanov', 1985, 'Engineer'), 
(Timestamp('2020-01-14 00:00:00'), 'Smith', 1964, 'Public Agent'), 
(Timestamp('2020-01-15 00:00:00'), 'Pitt', 1977, 'Actor')]
```

How I can replace timestamp to string, like this:

```
[('2020-01-13 00:00:00', 'Ivanov', 1985, 'Engineer'), 
('2020-01-14 00:00:00', 'Smith', 1964, 'Public Agent'), 
('2020-01-15 00:00:00', 'Pitt', 1977, 'Actor')]
```

Comment: Try `[[str(i)] + rest for i, *rest in tups]`?

Comment: your `read_zip`, does it work as intended? how does `df` look like?

Comment: @MrFuppes I changed

Comment: I don't see why you would want to extract the content of the Dataframe to a list of tuples. Instead, manipulate the data in the df, e.g. `df['timestring'] = df['name-of-timestamp-col'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` creates a column with your desired format.